# How to start Delayed Job with Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I use [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v4.1.2) as a queuing backend for Active Job on my Rails 5 app but I have no idea how to start the worker on Ubuntu 14.04 after startup. Should I wrap `rails jobs:work` into a Bash script? How would I have it start automatically? Or is it preferable to use `bin/delayed_job`?

How do I start delayed job on boot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not really matter what OS you're on (as long it is not Windows :D).

To start the processing the command is:

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

to restart the delayed_job the command is:

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart
```

Check out [gems README](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for more info.

## EDIT

(according to the comment)

You can create some  bash script in user's home `start_delayed_jon.sh`.

Something along the lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/your/project/directory/
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

and run it in /etc/rc.local:

```
su -s /bin/bash - deploy /path/to/your/project/directory/start_delayed_jon.sh
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I start it on my dev machine but how to I have Ubuntu start it automatically at server boot?

Comment: @ilovebigmacs please let me know whether my answer was helpful or should I delete it

Comment: Doesn't really feel like a robust way to do it. Waiting for more answers.

Comment: @ilovebigmacs firing a script on system boot that launches something does not sound like a robust way of launching something on system boot? :)

Comment: True. I will accept the answer and re-ask it better. Meaning "how should it be done properly?". If you use this, you'll never know if the job fails or stops working. A crontab restarting it every hour or so seems better.

Answer (score 7):

Using the [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever), you can setup a cronjob that runs it on reboot. In your schedule.rb file:

```
every :reboot do
 rake 'start_delayed_jobs'
end
```

Then in your rake file:

```
desc 'Start delayed jobs'
  task :start_delayed_jobs do
    system("#{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start")
  end
end
```

Comment: This works, but quick fix on the typo --> system("#{Rails.root}/bin/delayed_job start")

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`.
You start a delayed jobs on your local ubuntu system, simply run the below command to start

```
./bin/delayed_job start
```

and to restart

```
./bin/delayed_job restart
```

If we are in development mode, we would use the below rake task instead.

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Answer (score 0):

for production:

```
    RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n2 restart
     
 or

    RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n2 restart
```

n2 is the number of delayed jobs servers you want to restart in case of start use command start instead or restart.

documentation: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#restarting-delayed_job